# How to configure IBM Filenet Content Navigator to view multi-content document?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-content-navigator

I have a `document` which consists of multiple contents, let's say a `msword` file, an `jpeg` image file and a `mp4` video file, and when the user clicks on that `document` in content navigator, he must be able to see the contents available as we get in Workplace XT.

A separate link for `msword`,`jepg` and `mp4`. Is it possible to configure ICN like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICN does not provide an option to view multiple content elements as separate file - like Workplace / XT. However, using the viewer, you can navigate between multiple content elements. If you have a requirement to provide this option, it is pretty easy. You can create a plugin for displaying multiple content elements and add it to document context menu. You can probably create a custom dialog widget to display these content elements as separate links.